# Iterating hashmap of arraylist of two different Class types

Tags: java, object, arraylist, hashmap

I have to create an hashmap of arraylist but arraylist can be of type StudentRecord or TeacherRecord(which are two different classes) I have added  both the records but I am not able to iterate through the contents of hashmap using display method.can anybody help me to define the display function?

```
public class StudentRecord 
    {
        String first_Name;
        String last_Name;
        String [] courses_Registered;
        String status;
        Date date;

    StudentRecord(String f_name,String l_name,String [] courses,String status,Date dat )
    {
        this.first_Name=f_name;
        this.last_Name=l_name;
        this.courses_Registered=courses;
        this.status=status;
        this.date=dat;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class TeacherRecord 
{
    String first_Name;
    String last_Name;
    String address;
    String phone;
    String specilization;
    String location;

    TeacherRecord(String f_name,String l_name,String addr,String number,String spec,String loc )
    {
        this.first_Name=f_name;
        this.last_Name=l_name;
        this.address=addr;
        this.phone=number;
        this.location=loc;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Montreal_server
{

    String record_id;
    ArrayList<StudentRecord> student_arraylist=new ArrayList<StudentRecord>();
    ArrayList<TeacherRecord>teacher_arraylist=new ArrayList<TeacherRecord>();

    HashMap<String,ArrayList> map=new HashMap<String,ArrayList>();

    void createTRecord(String f_name,String l_name,String addr,String number,String spec,String loc)
    {
        TeacherRecord t=new TeacherRecord(f_name,l_name,addr,number,spec,loc);
        teacher_arraylist.add(t);
        map.put("x",teacher_arraylist);


    }

    void createSRecord(String f_name,String l_name,String [] courses,String status,Date dat)
    {
        StudentRecord s=new StudentRecord(f_name,l_name,courses,status,dat);
        student_arraylist.add(s);
        map.put("s",student_arraylist);




    }

    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("inside display");
        for(Entry<String, ArrayList> en : map.entrySet())
        {
            java.util.Iterator<StudentRecord> itr = ((List<StudentRecord>)student_arraylist).iterator();



            while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                Object c=(Object)itr.next();

                System.out.println(c.first_Name+" "+c.last_Name+" "+c.status+" "+c.date+" "+c.courses_Registered);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: create an interface that both Student and Teacher implement and then just use an ArrayList

Comment: The real question is, why are you stuffing both lists in to a single map and passing them to a single method? Why not print them separately?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to override `toString()` on each of your classes:

```
public class StudentRecord {
    // fields, constructor etc.

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return first_Name+" "+last_Name+" "+status+" "+date+" "+Arrays.toString(courses_Registered);  
    }
}
```

Create a similar method for `TeacherRecord`. Now, in your loop, simply call `System.out.println(c);`, which will implicitly print the result of your `toString()` implementation.

Additionally, a lot of the confusion is a result of trying to coerce lists containing unrelated types into a single map. The simplest solution is to just print each list separately:

```
void display() {
    student_arraylist.forEach(System.out::println);
    teacher_arraylist.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: @NimChimpsky I'm sorry you feel that way.

Comment: @kamalpreetkaur Please explain.

Comment: i ran this code in main ms.createSRecord("kamalpreet", "kaur", str, "active",new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()) );
  ms.createTRecord("hi","bye","lhx","+123","mnt", "gf");
  ms.display(); but output shown is Student record twice like  kamalpreet kaur active Mon May 22 20:21:47 EDT 2017 [a, b]
kamalpreet kaur active Mon May 22 20:21:47 EDT 2017 [a, b]

Comment: @kamalpreetkaur You're looping over `map.entrySet()`, but your iterator points to the same `student_arraylist`, so you're seeing the same values for each entry.

Comment: it showed student record twice bcz in code i have invoked iterator on student_arraylist .

Comment: yes i understood that point but can you tell me how i should write iterator statement?

Comment: @kamalpreetkaur See the recommendation in my update.

Answer (score 0):

Have both classes implement a common interface, eg

```
public interface PersonRecord {
String firstName();
String lastName();
...
}
```

and

```
public class StudentRecord implements PersonRecord
    { ... }
```

which allows

```
List<PersonRecord> students = new List<>();
students.add(new StudentRecord());
```

Comment: This doesn't help unless OP only wants to print common fields, which clearly is not the case.

Comment: Really a combination of your's and @shmosel answer is required

Comment: sorry i didnt understand the purpose of creating an interface  as which functions i should include in interface as both classes have different data

Comment: But they also have common data and common methods